# How to bind object throw multi child elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**TLDR**: How to define and upward pass a common property throw 3 registered elements?

Assume that you have a parent interface element and call it dashboard, now `<dashboard>` has a child element called `<tree-node>` which includes another child element inside it called `<tree-node-element>` which prompts the user to push some data into an array called chapters.

How to pass chapters object from `<tree-node-element>` upwards to `<dashboard>`, should I define chapters property in each element, what flags should I give that property in each definition.

Polymer V1x

Answer (score 0):

Use event bubbling, so `fire()` the event `node-element-foo-changed` and listen for it in the dashboard element.

This is probably late stage, but you can also for example use Redux or data mixins for state management in your application.

Comment: Polymer 1x dosent support bubbling

Answer (score 0):

Define the chapters property on the top node, dashboard. Propagate it down through the tree via polymer data binding. Have the child node (tree-node-element) emit an event to change the value. Have the dashboard element listen for the event and update the value with this.set(). The value will then automatically propagate down to all the child nodes in the tree. That way you only need to implement the logic to update the data in one place.

Comment: now I am able to catch changes on child element through observe but still not able to capture it in the parent elements